# C data type sizes intmax_t vs any other integer, void * vs any other pointer

Tags: c, sizeof

Is it true that:

- No data pointer is larger than `sizeof(void *)`?
- No data pointer is larger than `sizeof(char *)`?
- No integer is larger than `sizeof(intmax_t)`?
- Neither `float` nor `double` are larger than `sizeof(long double)`?

I know that `intmax_t` can store any value any other signed integer can store, but is it required that the size is also the largest size of any integer? Or is it possible that some other integer uses so many more padding bits than `intmax_t` that the size of that integer becomes larger than `intmax_t` even when this integer can't hold any value that `intmax_t` can't hold?

Similarly to pointers, i know that any other data pointer can by converted to `char *` and `void *` and back again without losing information, but does that mean the size of `char *` and `void *` has to be the largest possible size of all data pointers?

I ask this question because i have a function in a library that converts a string to a different type which is indicated by an integer. To test if this conversation can be done for a given string (the format is correct) a function exists that test this for different data types, the function should reserve enough memory for all possible types, do the conversation, check for errors, and free this memory again. Is it enough to make sure it is large enough for `intmax_t` to cover all integer types?

Comment: The C standard does not require these. An implementation could, say, include metadata with `int *` that it does not with `void *`, making `int *` larger than `void *` even though it cannot address as many distinct locations. Or it could just say screw you and pad `float` with a hundred unused bytes. Or maybe a `void *` is just eight bytes to access any 64-bit address but all function pointers are 16 bytes because they include some security information.

Comment: @EricPostpischil To the function pointers: There is no requirement in C that `void *` can hold a function pointer, in fact on some micro controllers with harvard architecture a function pointer is larger than `void *`. For the rest: This belongs into an answer.

Comment: The short non-technical version is a pointer-is-a-pointer-is-a-pointer (and there is only one size for any given implementation). The `stdint.h` type `intmax_t` can hold any signed integer value, and without considering odd 12-bit floating-point, or precision greater than `double` etc. then it's generally safe to presume that neither `float` or `double` are larger than `long double`. But as noted, the standard doesn't specifically answer your question, so it will be implementation specific (though I know of none that violate your statements)

Comment: There is a reason why the C standard does not require that "a pointer-is-a-pointer-is-a-pointer (and there is only one size for any given implementation)." The reason being that this is simply not true for several (formerly) important architectures. http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: "No integer is larger than sizeof(intmax_t)" - `sizeof(intmax_t)` is usually 4 or 8.

Answer (score 1):

There's an `intptr_t` now that's guaranteed to work; however the platforms of years past where `intptr_t` would need to be larger than `ptrdiff_t` don't have `intptr_t` because they're frozen in time, and the native compilers for the target platforms just don't have it. If you have a modern compiler such as OpenWatcom targeting the old architectures it would work.

While they did fix this stuff for modern compilers cross-compiling to embedded CPUs, you end up with other aberrations that could exist instead that are just as bad and equally hard to test for. The compilers I've had to deal with in the embedded world had some real nasties; if these are typical, trying to make a platform neutral library that doesn't assume flat architecture is fraught with pearl:

- NULL is not 0. This means that `memset()` doesn't initialize pointers in structures to NULL and neither does `calloc()`; nor are they NULL when declared as static unless explicitly initialized to `NULL`.
- `sizeof(char *) < sizeof(const char *)` and `sizeof(void *) < sizeof(const void *)`; this particular compiler didn't give an `intptr_t` and `ptrdiff_t` could not contain the result of arbitrary subtraction of two pointers in the same character array (but was avoidable by making the character array no bigger than PTRDIFF_T_MAX).
- Compiler didn't implement C99 and didn't have an `intptr_t` and `ptrdiff_t` was too small to hold a pointer.
- `free()` didn't do anything
- The compiler statically removed null pointer tests where it could prove the pointer pointed to a struct, but NULL was a possible address of a global variable.

I've never tried to make a nontrivial library work in the embedded world and certainly never one that messed with pointers like this.

TL;DR All your four assertions ought to be true, but when put to the test by fire where it matters you end up dealing with ugliness.

It occurs to me if you're converting between pointer and string, `sprintf` and `sscanf` have format specifiers that can do this.

Comment: The first and last sentence is not true.

Comment: where _`intptr_t` would need to be larger than `ptrdiff_t` don't have `intptr_t`_ I don't see why that should be the case, nor this: _if you can't cast the pointer to `ptrdiff_t` safely `intmax_t` won't exist at all either_  can you explain why this should be the case?  AFAIK: This statements are wrong for some 8051 compilers.

Comment: OpenWatcom for 8086 using the memory model LARGE is an example of a compiler/library that uses 32 bit for `intptr_t`, but `ptrdiff_t` is only 16 bit and `intmax_t` exists. Is that non-conforming? https://github.com/jmalak/open-watcom/blob/master/bld/hdr/watcom/stdint.mh

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Big update to answer; I added lots of stuff from the embedded world. I'm surprised that somebody is maintaining an x86-16 compiler to the modern standards but there it is so I included it in the answer.